# How can I change the request body in Swagger 1.5 to an example JSON request body

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-ui, dropwizard

[Current look of Swagger request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehr4h.png)

Is it possible to change the body

```
{
  "config": {
    "additionalProp1": {},
    "additionalProp2": {},
    "additionalProp3": {}
  },
  "class": "string"
}
```

to look like

```
{
"class": "my.class.com",
"config": {
    "myParam": "",
    "datacenter": "USA",
}
```

Currently the method looks like this

```
@POST
@Path("/run")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(value = "Runs a specified job asynchronously",
    notes = "Doesn't work for full tasks.")
public Response createTask(TaskConfig taskConfig) {
```

TaskConfig is a basic class with two member variables

```
public class TaskConfig {
    @JsonProperty("class")
    @NotNull
    private String clazz;

    private Map<String, Object> config;
```

We are using Swagger 1.5 from this [Dropwizard Swagger bundle library.](https://github.com/smoketurner/dropwizard-swagger) I know that 2.0 has the @RequestBody annotation and I just want to make sure that is my only option before I go down the path of upgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even by using `@RequestBody` we need to add additional annotation within `TaskConfig` class.

We are using Swagger 2.0.x. The TaskConfig class would have fields something like this :

```
@Schema(
  description = " My descriptions",
  type = "array",
  example = " {\"myParam\" :\"value\" ,"
      + "\"datacenter\": \"USA\"}")
private Map<String, Object> config;
```

Similarly `clazz` can also be annotated like :

```
@Schema(description = "The field descrition", example = "true")
```

And `RequestBody` annotation will look like :

```
@RequestBody(
  description = "Description of TaskConfig ",
  content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = TaskConfig .class)))
```

I got the result as shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: The OP wanted for 1.5 not 2.